# Field Calculator for Multiple Fields

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-10.8, error-000989

I am trying to get field calculator to work on 2 fields with multiple lines.

Trying to have anything within RS10/R10 > 100,000 to return 1 if not then 0, also same results RS15/R15 > 150,000, and RS20/R20 > 200,000

This is the Pre-logic Script Code:

```
def calc( ZONE_DESC , Sqft ):
if (ZONE_DESC = RS10)and(Sqft = > 100000):
    return '1'
else:
    return '0' 
if (ZONE_DESC = R10)and(Sqft = > 100000):
    return '1'
else:
    return '0' 
if (ZONE_DESC = RS15)and(Sqft = > 150000):
    return '1'
else:
    return '0' 
if (ZONE_DESC = R15)and(Sqft = > 150000):
    return '1'
else:
    return '0' 
if (ZONE_DESC = RS20)and(Sqft = > 200000):
    return '1'
else:
    return '0
if (ZONE_DESC = R20)and(Sqft = > 200000):
    return '1'
else:
    return '0'
```

This is what I have in the second box:

```
 calc( !ZONE_DESC! , !Sqft! )
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 000989 Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 2)'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Your [indentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp) is incorrect,
2. `=` should be `==`,
3. `=>` should be `>=`
4. `RS10` etc. needs to be enclosed in quotes `'RS10'`.
5. You can shorten the code by using `elif` and one `else` at the end.

Try this:

```
def calc( ZONE_DESC , Sqft ):
    if (ZONE_DESC == 'RS10') and (Sqft >= 100000):
        return '1'
    elif (ZONE_DESC == 'R10') and (Sqft >= 100000):
        return '1'
    elif (ZONE_DESC == 'RS15') and (Sqft >= 150000):
        return '1'
    elif (ZONE_DESC == 'R15') and (Sqft >= 150000):
        return '1'
    elif (ZONE_DESC == 'RS20') and (Sqft >= 200000):
        return '1'
    elif (ZONE_DESC == 'R20') and (Sqft >= 200000):
        return '1'
    else:
        return '0'
```

Comment: I'd recommend adding PEP8 conformance: 6. Variable names should be lowercase (`zone_desc` and `sqft`)